# flask python add 404 page

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to add custom 404 page.

I have this code:

```
#404 page
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('/404.html'), 404
```

But It doesn't work 
I still get

> 2017-10-10 09:24:04,983:   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 61,
>   in get_source 2017-10-10 09:24:04,983:     raise
>   TemplateNotFound(template)

UPD: 
I HAVE 404.html file in my templates folder!
[image]

Comment: it can't find the template file, it doesn't have anything to do with 404 error. that error come's up when you have no view.

Comment: `render_template` takes files from the `template/` directory. Create a template directory and place your file in it or do it in a way where you can give a full file path.

Comment: @Vj- see an update

Comment: @senaps - see an update

Answer (score 2):

its like the template cannot be found

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
  return render_template('path_folder/404.html'), 404
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the template is not where you expect to find it.

Can you try to put in `/static` and read it from there?

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return send_from_directory("static", "404.html"), 404
```